# Incorporating multiple classes of images in Rails (4) project

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm trying to build an app that would let users upload photos.  I have been able to do this with carrierwave.  I also want to let users add a custom profile image.  I tried using gravatar first, but now that I have carrierwave installed would prefer to use that and related functionality for editing, etc. I plan to include.  Do I need to create a separate profile image model or should I build it into the user model?

Gravatar did not seem to have a separate model.  I don't want to repeat work if it is unnecessary to create a separate ProfileimageUploader, MVC, etc.  but I'm unsure how to proceed and what best practice is for coding this.  Most resources I have found talk only about adding one class of images, but not how to deal with having different classes that `belongs_to` different models.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CarrierWave maps a single field to a single file, using an object it calls an uploader.

If a user has exactly one profile image, and users can't share one profile image, then I'd mount the uploader on a field on User.

If a user can have more than one profile image, or more than one user can share the same profile image, I'd create a ProfileImage model and mount the uploader on a field there.